# How to create a xmlnode as in given format in asp.net web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-config

I want to add a new rule in my web.config file programmatically, But i am not able and get an error

> "System.Exception: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.".

My code is as follows..

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

         bool change = false;
         string configFile = Path.Combine( Server.MapPath("~").ToString(), "web.config");
         doc.Load(configFile);

 XmlNode xmlNode1 = cfg.XmlSection.SelectSingleNode("rewriteRules");
            XmlNode xmlNode = xmlNode1.SelectSingleNode("rule");
            if (xmlNode != null)
            {

                string nodeFormat = string.Format("<rule source='{0}'  destination='{1}' />", source, destination);
try
                {

                    XmlElement xmlElement = (XmlElement)(xmlNode.SelectSingleNode(nodeFormat));//error occured
                    if (xmlElement != null)
                    {
                        //xmlElement.SetAttribute("source", source);
                        //xmlElement.SetAttribute("destination", destination);
                        //xmlNode.AppendChild(xmlElement);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        xmlElement = doc.CreateElement("rule");
                        xmlElement.SetAttribute("source", source);
                        xmlElement.SetAttribute("destination", destination);
                        xmlNode.AppendChild(xmlElement);
                    }
                    doc.Save(configFile);
                    //SaveWebConfig( xmlDoc );
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
```

Please help me...

Comment: On what line of code does it give that exception?

Comment: @McKay Judging by the comments - `XmlElement xmlElement = (XmlElement)(xmlNode.SelectSingleNode(nodeFormat));//error occured`

Comment: @social should this string `<rule @source='{0}'  @destination='{1}'` have the `@` symbol in it? Is that valid XML?

Comment: @DGibbs My rules are in web.config is as follows..<modulesSection>
  <rewriteModule>
   <rewriteOn>true</rewriteOn>
   <rewriteRules>
    <rule source="About/About-Ashoka" destination="About/About.aspx"/>

Comment: @DGibbs ah, yeah, it was just off the screen

Comment: @social What is the purpose of the `@` before the attributes on the `rule` element?

Comment: @DGibbs Ya sorry that was wrong code i have removed @ but still gettting previous error. its urgent please help me sir..

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use LINQ to XML? It's much easier for querying/updating XML files.

For example, you could have a method to query the XML and return true/false if the element exists depending on `source` and `destination` attributes

```
public static bool RuleExists(string source, string destination)
{
     XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current
                              .Server.MapPath("your file"));

     return doc.Descendants("rewriteRules").Elements()
               .Where(e => e.Attribute("source").Value == source 
               && e.Attribute("destination").Value == destination).Any();
}
```

This would tell you if the rule already exists. You could then modify your existing code to something like this:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("your file"));

//replace with actual source/destination
if (RuleExists("About/About-Ashoka", "About/About.aspx"))
{
     //element is already in the config file
     //do something...
}
else
{
     XElement elem = new XElement("rule");
     elem.SetAttributeValue("source", source);
     elem.SetAttributeValue("destination", destination);
     xml.Element("rewriteRules").Add(elem);
     xml.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("your file"));
 }
```

Comment: Sir I have getting an error 'rewriteRules[rule[source='abhi/abhitheflame' and destination='abhi/abhitheflame.aspx']' has an invalid token.

Comment: At this line  xml.Element("rewriteRules").Add(elem); I have getting an error that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."...

Comment: Correct code is xml.Descendants("rewriteRules").First().Add(elem); thank you so much sir...

Comment: @social Happy to help. If this answers your question, please upvote and accept it as the answer so that it may help others in the future